# ValueError Expected singleton

Tags: odoo

```
class Aveant(models.Model):
_name=  'facturation.avenant'
_description    =   'Avenant'
contrat_id  =   fields.Many2one('facturation.contrat')
travSup_ids = fields.One2many('facturation.travsup','attachment_id',compute='display_trav')


@api.multi
@api.onchange('contrat_id')
def display_trav(self):

    if self.contrat_id:

        attachements=self.env["facturation.attachement"].search([('contrat_id','=',self.contrat_id.id)])

        print attachements.id
        trv=self.env["facturation.travsup"].search([('attachment_id','=',attachements.id)])
        print trv
        for obj in self:
            obj.travSup_ids = trv
```

how to correct this error :Expected singleton: facturation.attachement(3, 4, 6, 7)

code xml:

```
 <field name="travSup_ids">
<tree editable="True">
    <field name="ouvrage_id"/>
    <field name="article_id"/>
    </tree>         
</field>
```

how to display in view???

Comment: It may have more details that will surly helpful for future development. https://odedrabhavesh.blogspot.in/2017/02/valueerror-expected-singleton-in-odoo.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got recordset more than one in `attachements` variable. So you may try with following code to resolve it.

```
trv = self.env["facturation.travsup"].search(
    [('attachment_id','in',attachements.ids)])
```

Answer (score 0):

You use  attachements.id as it was a single value, but probably with this code

```
self.env["facturation.attachement"].search([('contrat_id','=',self.contrat_id.id)])
```

you get more objects. I think you should use '==' instead of '=' :

```
self.env["facturation.attachement"].search([('contrat_id','==',self.contrat_id.id)])
```